# Map area in a Select element

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am looking for how to do a searcher like [this](https://www.balearic-villas.com/) (The select with a map area)

I've done a select, but I don't know how to integrate a map area like [that](https://www.balearic-villas.com/) for select a destination.

```
<div class="form-group">
<select class="selectTbx" id="combobox" placeholder="Zone" name="zone">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <%=this.strOptions %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the website that you have shown, first search box does not seem to have a search functionality, its just a text box and onclick of it its showing a DIV with contents. You can do the same easily with JQuery/Javascript